# XCode 14.3.1 - M1 runner - xcodebuild - UI tests doesn't create clones of simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild, xcuitest, rosetta

I'm having problems with UI tests on an M1 runner using Xcode 14.3.1. In my project, I need to build using the Rosetta simulator because I have a dependency that is not updated to support the arm simulator. This dependency relies on OpenCV.

This is the command that I use when I want to run UI tests on CI:

```
xcodebuild ARCHS=x86_64 clean test
        -scheme UITests
        -configuration Debug
        -destination 'id=50E9C593-9A40-4E4D-B58D-1DE437CFBE3A'
        -parallel-testing-enabled YES
        -parallel-testing-worker-count 4
        -maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations 4 
        -test-iterations 3
        -retry-tests-on-failure
```

And this code run ui tests only with 1 clone of simulator. Anyone know why?